Rasa response issue
I'm new in Rasa i want create endpoint where i always get details
{
  "version": "3.3.1",
  "session_id": null,
  "request": {
    "user_utterance": "Hey",
    "metadata": {
      "store_id": "200"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "intent": "None",
    "entity": [],
    "confidence": 0.0,
    "message": "Hey! How are you?"
  }
}

something like this i used this

class NluChannel(InputChannel):
    def name(cls) -> Text:
        """Name of your custom channel."""
        return "nluchannel"

    def _extract_metadata(self, req: Request) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        metadata = req.json.get("metadata")
        if not isinstance(metadata, dict):
            metadata = {}
        return metadata

    def blueprint(
        self, on_new_message: Callable[[UserMessage], Awaitable[None]]
    ) -> Blueprint:

        custom_webhook = Blueprint(
            "custom_webhook_{}".format(type(self).__name__),
            inspect.getmodule(self).__name__,
        )

        @custom_webhook.route("/", methods=["GET"])
        async def health(request: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
            return response.json({"status": "ok"})

        @custom_webhook.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
        async def receive(request: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
            sender_id = request.json.get("session_id") 
            text = request.json.get("text") 
            input_channel = self.name() 
            metadata = self._extract_metadata(request) 

            validate_request_body(
                request,
                "No text message defined in request_body. Add text message to request body "
                "in order to obtain the intent and extracted entities.",
            )
            emulation_mode = request.args.get("emulation_mode")
            emulator = _create_emulator(emulation_mode)

            collector = CollectingOutputChannel() 
            try:
                # Create a message object and handle the message
                message = UserMessage(
                    text,
                    collector,
                    sender_id,
                    input_channel=input_channel,
                    metadata=metadata,
                )
                await on_new_message(message)

                # Extract the intent and confidence from the parsed data
                for message in collector.messages:
                    print(message, "-----------------")
                    # Extract intent and entities from each message
                    parse_data = message.get("parse_data")
                    if parse_data:
                        intent = parse_data.get("intent", {}).get("name")
                        entities = parse_data.get("entities", [])
                        print("Intent:", intent)
                        print("Entities:", entities)
                parsed_data = collector.messages[0].get("parse_data") if collector.messages else None
                if parsed_data:
                    intent_name = parsed_data["intent"]["name"]
                    intent_confidence = parsed_data["intent"]["confidence"]
                    entities = parsed_data.get("entities", [])
                else:
                    intent_name = "None"
                    intent_confidence = 0.0
                    entities = []

                # Extract the bot's message
                bot_message = collector.messages[0]['text'] if collector.messages else "No response"

            except Exception as e:
                logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
                raise ErrorResponse(
                    HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                    "ParsingError",
                    f"An unexpected error occurred. Error: {e}",
                )

            response_data = {
                "version": rasa_version,
                "session_id": sender_id,
                "request": {
                    "user_utterance": text,
                    "metadata": metadata,
                },
                "response": {
                    "intent": intent_name,
                    "entity": entities,
                    "confidence": intent_confidence,
                    "message": bot_message
                }
            }

            return response.json(response_data)

        return custom_webhook


await on_new_message(message) collector.messages then it only return trained models details like if i said hey then it return how are you. but my need is different i added in my config.yml
- name: actions.categories.DataBaseCategoryEntity
  min_confidence: 0.75 in my config.yml and

this is my category extractor

from typing import Dict, Text, Any, List
from rasa.engine.graph import GraphComponent, ExecutionContext
from rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.message import Message
from rasa.engine.storage.storage import ModelStorage
from rasa.engine.storage.resource import Resource
from rasa.shared.nlu.training_data.training_data import TrainingData
from rasa.engine.recipes.default_recipe import DefaultV1Recipe
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams
import os
import logging 
from rasa_sdk import Tracker
from utils.api_requests import ApiRequest

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

try:
    from cfuzzyset import cFuzzySet as FuzzySet
except ImportError:
    from fuzzyset import FuzzySet





@DefaultV1Recipe.register(
    [DefaultV1Recipe.ComponentType.MESSAGE_TOKENIZER], is_trainable=False
)
class DataBaseCategoryEntity(GraphComponent):
    def __init__(self, config, model_storage, resource, execution_context) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.url = os.getenv("ALL_CATEGORIES_URL")
        self.categories_list = []
        self.categories_entity = []
        self.entities = []
        self.min_confidence = config.get("min_confidence", 0.5)
        
    @classmethod
    def create(
        cls,
        config: Dict[Text, Any],
        model_storage: ModelStorage,
        resource: Resource,
        execution_context: ExecutionContext,
    ) -> GraphComponent:
        # TODO: Implement this
        return cls(config, model_storage, resource, execution_context)

    def train(self, training_data: TrainingData) -> Resource:
        # TODO: Implement this if your component requires training
        ...

    def process_training_data(self, training_data: TrainingData) -> TrainingData:
        # TODO: Implement this if your component augments the training data with
        #       tokens or message features which are used by other components
        #       during training.
        ...

        return training_data
    
    def _get_category(self, store_id):
        try:
            print(self.url)
            body = {"store_id": store_id}
            data = ApiRequest.post_request(self.url, body)
            categories = []
            for each_category in data:
                categories.append(
                    {
                        "category_id": each_category.get("category_id"),
                        "category": each_category.get("category_name"),
                        "store_id": each_category.get("store_id")
                    }
                )

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            categories = []

        return categories

    def process(self, messages: List[Message]) -> List[Message]:
        """
        Process an incoming message by determining the most similar (or matching) names.
        """
        for message in messages:
            tracker = message.get("metadata")
            store_id = tracker.get("store_id")
            categories = self._get_category(store_id)
            self.categories_list.extend(categories)
            self.categories_entity = self._load(self.categories_list)
            extracted = self.match_entities(message)
            message.set(
                "entities", message.get("entities", []) + extracted, add_to_output=True
            )
        return messages

    def _load(self, categories):
        self.entities = []
        for each_category in categories:
            fuzzy = FuzzySet()
            fuzzy.add(each_category.get("category"))
            self.entities.append(
                {
                    "category_id": each_category.get("category_id"),
                    "category": each_category.get("category"),
                    "store_id": each_category.get("store_id"),
                    "fuzzy": fuzzy,
                }
            )

    def match_entities(self, message: Message):
        """
        Perform fuzzy matching on each token of the message.
        A token contains its text, its offset, its end and optionally additional data.
        """
        extracted_entities = []
        text = message.data.get("text")
        print(message, message.data, "all messages....")
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        token_positions = [(token, text.index(token), text.index(token)+len(token)) for token in tokens]

        # Handle multi-word entities
        for n in range(1, 6):  # specify the range of n-gram lengths to consider
            ngrams_list = list(ngrams(tokens, n))
            for ngram in ngrams_list:
                token_text = " ".join(ngram)
                for each_entity in self.entities:
                    fuzzy_matches = each_entity.get("fuzzy").get(token_text, [])
                    for match in fuzzy_matches:
                        if match[0] < self.min_confidence:
                            continue  # skip low-confidence entities
                        entity = {
                        "start": token_positions[tokens.index(ngram[0])][1],
                        "end": token_positions[tokens.index(ngram[-1])][2],
                        "value": each_entity.get("category"),
                        "confidence": match[0],
                        "entity": "category_name",
                        "val": each_entity.get("category_id"),
                        "key": "category_id",
                        "store_id": each_entity.get("store_id")
                        }
                        extracted_entities.append(entity)
        return extracted_entities
 

here i want based on my payload metadata's store_id it return details when i use UserMessage i can get store_id in this class but in collectors.message it return always [] and when i'm using
class NluChannel(InputChannel):
    def name(cls) -> Text:
        """Name of your custom channel."""
        return "nluchannel"

    def _extract_metadata(self, req: Request) -> Text:
        return req.json.get("metadata") or self.name()

    def blueprint(
        self, on_new_message: Callable[[UserMessage], Awaitable[None]]
    ) -> Blueprint:

        custom_webhook = Blueprint(
            "custom_webhook_{}".format(type(self).__name__),
            inspect.getmodule(self).__name__,
        )

        @custom_webhook.route("/", methods=["GET"])
        async def health(request: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
            return response.json({"status": "ok"})

        @custom_webhook.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
        async def receive(request: Request) -> HTTPResponse:
            sender_id = request.json.get("session_id") # method to get sender_id 
            text = request.json.get("text") # method to fetch text
            input_channel = self.name() # method to fetch input channel
            metadata = self._extract_metadata(request) # method to get metadata

            validate_request_body(
            request,
            "No text message defined in request_body. Add text message to request body "
            "in order to obtain the intent and extracted entities.",
            )
            emulation_mode = request.args.get("emulation_mode")
            emulator = _create_emulator(emulation_mode)

            try:
                data = emulator.normalise_request_json(request.json)
                try:
                    parsed_data = await request.app.ctx.agent.parse_message(data.get("text"))
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
                    raise ErrorResponse(
                        HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                        "ParsingError",
                        f"An unexpected error occurred. Error: {e}",
                    )
                _response = Response()

                # response_data = emulator.normalise_response_json(parsed_data)

                return response.json(_response.create_response(sender_id,text,metadata,parsed_data))

            except Exception as e:
                logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
                raise ErrorResponse(
                    HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "ParsingError",
                    f"An unexpected error occurred. Error: {e}",
                )

        return custom_webhook

in my channel then i have to pass my store_ids in list in my config.yml. which i don't need and here parse_message have only text sending option when i change this function to add accept metadata then it's work but while create docker container i'm facing issue
ImportError: cannot import name 'MessageProcessor' from partially initialized module 'rasa.core.processor' (most likely due to a circular import)
and this is my payload so i want to know is there any option where i can pass my metadata?
{
  "sender": "test_user",
  "text": "I want to select burgers",
  "metadata": {
    "store_id": "200"
  }
} 


